Why do Bryant Solitons include time flow-components in the metric?
I'm reading Robert Bryant's notes on Ricci flow solitons in 3D with rotational symmetry and I'm a little confused by the 3D case for Ricci solitons as described by Dr. Bryant. He describes, for the equation:
$$
Ric(g) = Hess_g(f) - \lambda g
$$
the ansatz of rotationally symmetric metrics of form
$$
g = dt^2 + a(t)^2 \ (d\theta^2 + sin(\theta) d\phi^2)
$$
I see that this is indeed a 3D metric, but for t the parameter from the original Ricci flow equation $Ric(g) = \partial_t g$, why is it being treated like a coordinate for the manifold that g describes? Why do have a $dt^2$?
I'm trying to understand Ricci flow from the perspective of surface embeddings. Is it possible to look at metrics of form $dr^2 + r(t)^2 (d\theta^2 + sin(\theta)d\phi^2)$ and obtain an induced metric for some non-trivial $r(t,x_i)$? This would embed a 2D surface in 3D space so I'm not sure if it's permissible to treat an induced metric of form $g_1 d\theta^2 + g_2d\phi^2$ as a Bryant soliton. The surface generated by $r(t,x_i)$ can be chosen to be rotationally symmetric obviously. If one embeds such a surface, when taking the exterior derivative of $r(t,x_i)$, am I supposed to include the term $\partial_t r \ dt$?
I think since mathematicians refer to the parameter $t$ in the ricci flow equation sometimes as time that there might be a flaw in my argument regarding $r(t,x_i)$. For an induced metric to satisfy the ricci flow equation, would the coordinates have to be parameterized by $t$?

I think this $t$ is unrelated to the time parameter $t$ of Ricci flow.

@AnthontCarapetis at the beginning of the paper I'm reading here , he uses t in both the ricci flow and for the metric ansatz

Yeah, it's confusing and unnecessary to reuse $t$, but I'm pretty sure it's unrelated. Once you've established that the time-dependent solition behaviour (1.2) is equivalent to the time-independent equation (1.1), you no longer need to involve an explicit time parameter in your calculations.

@AnthontCarapetis ah interesting! so the t in the metric here is just another coordinate I presume? I can define some function $t(\theta, \phi)$ and induce a metric here that generates the metric ansatz he states (such that we get an a(t) function like he has)?
